# Form cleaning and processing not working - Django

Tags: django, forms, validation, view

Alright, this is probably a really obvious problem and I'm just not seeing it, but I need help:

In the following view, I process a formset.
If the user fills the form, I want to save `EventRecord` and `ArticleHistory`, if the user leaves the form empty, I want to save *only* the `ArticleHistory`.

```
def process_form(formset, request, current_page, paginator):
    if formset.is_valid():
        for form in formset.forms:
            form = form.cleaned_data

            ##### Check if user filled the form
            if form["relevance"] == False:
                pass
            elif form["relevance"] == True:

                ##### If user filled the form, save EventRecord

                event_form = EventRecordForm()

                event = event_form.save(commit=False)
                event.article = paginator.page(current_page).object_list[0]
                event.coder = request.user.coder
                event.last_updated = datetime.datetime.today()
                event.event_date = form["event_date"]
                event.location = form["location"]
                event.actors = form["actors"]
                event.num_participants = form["num_participants"]
                event.issue = form["issue"]
                event.side = form["side"]
                event.scope = form["scope"]
                event.part_violence = form["part_violence"]
                event.sec_engagement = form["sec_engagement"]
                event.save()

        ##### Add info on who worked on the article when
        history_form = ArticleHistoryForm()
        article_history = history_form.save(commit=False)
        article_history.article = paginator.page(current_page).object_list[0]
        article_history.coder = request.user.coder
        article_history.last_updated = datetime.datetime.now()
        article_history.save()
```

I try to do that by cleaning the form like so:

```
class CodingForm(forms.Form):

    event_date = forms.DateField(required=False)
    location = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Location.objects.all(), required=False)
    actors = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
    num_participants = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)  
    issue = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)
    side = forms.NullBooleanField('Side')
    scope = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=SCOPE_CHOICES, coerce=int, empty_value=None)
    part_violence = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=PART_VIO, coerce=int, empty_value=None)
    sec_engagement = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=SEC_ENG, coerce=int, empty_value=None)
    relevance = forms.NullBooleanField('Relevance')

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        relevance = cleaned_data.get("relevance")
        event_date = cleaned_data.get("event_date")
        location = cleaned_data.get("location")

        if event_date and location:
            relevance = True
        else:
            relevance = False

        return cleaned_data
```

However, if I do it like this - no matter what I do - only `ArticleHistory` gets saved, and no `EventRecord`.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `clean` method, you're setting a local variable called `relevance` but not doing anything with it. I expect you want to set `cleaned_data['relevance']` to True or False instead.

Comment: For some weird reason, this isn't working anymore. I changed everything as you suggested, and it worked fine. But now I get a KeyError "relevance" in process_form: if form["relevance"] == False: What should I do?